# How can i predict images(outside dataset) using VGG16 with keras after training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, vgg-net

I have trained the VGG16 net using keras with my own dataset, which has 10 classes. so i modified the activation layer with 10 classes.

Here is the code

```
TRAIN_DIR = "D:\\Dataset\\training"   
VALIDATION_DIR = "D:\\Dataset\\validation"
```

part 2

```
   from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
IMAGE_WIDTH = 300
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 300
BATCH_SIZE = 16
```

part 3

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,      
                                    rotation_range=40,      
                                    width_shift_range=0.2,
                                    height_shift_range=0.2,
                                    shear_range=0.2,
                                    zoom_range=0.2,
                                    horizontal_flip=True, 
                                    fill_mode='nearest'
                                  )

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, 
                                  )

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAIN_DIR, 
                                                    target_size=(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT), 
                                                    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, 
                                                    shuffle=True, # By shuffling the images we add some randomness and prevent overfitting
                                                    class_mode="categorical")

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(VALIDATION_DIR, 
                                                    target_size=(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT), 
                                                    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, 
                                                    shuffle=True,
                                                    class_mode="categorical")
```

part 4

```
training_samples = 1097
validation_samples = 272
total_steps = training_samples // BATCH_SIZE
```

loading the VGG16

```
#VGG16 network with pretrained weights is used

from keras.applications import vgg16
model = vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, 3), pooling="max")

for layer in model.layers[:-5]:
        layer.trainable = False

for layer in model.layers:
    print(layer, layer.trainable)
```

part 5

```
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dropout
from keras.models import Model, Sequential

# Although this part can be done also with the functional API, I found that for this simple models, this becomes more intuitive
transfer_model = Sequential()
for layer in model.layers:
    transfer_model.add(layer)
transfer_model.add(Dense(512, activation="relu")) 
transfer_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
transfer_model.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
```

part 6

```
# Adam optimizer and learning rate 0.0001

from keras import optimizers
adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.00001)

transfer_model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
                      optimizer=adam,
                      metrics=["accuracy"])
```

finally the training

```
model_history = transfer_model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=training_samples // BATCH_SIZE,
                                            epochs=25,
                                            validation_data=validation_generator,
                                            validation_steps=validation_samples // BATCH_SIZE)
```

part 7, using some random images from the internet to predict

```
test_path = "D:\\Dataset\\predict\\"
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,      
                                    rotation_range=40,      
                                    width_shift_range=0.2,
                                    height_shift_range=0.2,
                                    shear_range=0.2,
                                    zoom_range=0.2,
                                    horizontal_flip=True, 
                                    fill_mode='nearest'
                                  )



test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_path, 
                                                    target_size=(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT), 
                                                    batch_size = 50, 
                                                    class_mode="categorical")
```

```
enter code here
```

in this part i am trying to predict, but getting this kind of numbers without getting the actual prediction result which i want as images

```
pred = model.predict_generator(test_generator, steps=1)
print(pred)
```

the result is like this, but i want these to be real images, but cannot figure out how.

[image]

Comment: you want to output _images_?

Comment: @NicolasGervais yes i want to check whether the trained model can identify the image classes or not, i tried several ways, sometimes it says expected activation to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 256, 256, 3)

Answer (score 0):

You can't output images from your network and it's not really clear how you imagine this would work - the images are the input and the output is a list of numbers with one value per class. You can interpret these numbers as the probability the image contains an object of that class.

You could then find the most likely class (using e.g. the `argmax` function) and show an image from this class if you liked - but this would have to be done separately.

Note - you are running the prediction using the original model not the `transfer_model`:

`pred = model.predict_generator(test_generator, steps=1)`

You should use the trained transfer model to get the class predictions and this will be in the form of a vector of 10 probabilities, one value for each class.